# Bootstrap modals not showing correctly when using Jinja templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jinja2

While using Jinja templates, Bootstrap modals do not show properly. Either they show without disabling the background or they show disabled (and can't be closed). Including a CSS z-index didn't work. Changing the JavaScript code to open the modal manually didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All modals need to be placed outside of your `<body>`. If you place the modals inside of your main jinja2 `{%block content%}`, they have a tendency to behave oddly. Try the following:

`template.html`- this is your main jinja2 template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        enter code here
        </head>

        <body>
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
        </body> 

        {%block modals%}
        {%endblock%}

</html>
```

Then on your child page, include the html below at the bottom of the page, after `{%endblock content%}`:

```html
{%block modals%}
<!-- Your modals go here -->
{%endblock%}
```